# undo 'npm run eject' in react

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I was trying to test the performance of my *React app*(created with create-react-app) with react CDN script and i did **'npm run eject'** to add [webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) dependencies  react and react-dom. 

 
I did that with ease in **webpack config** and `<script>` in `index.html`

```
...
externals: {
    react: 'React',
    'react-dom':'ReactDOM'
},
...
```

**Now I want to revert it back to previous state**

I am using **git** and i did this experiment in a seperate branch.

I ran `git checkout master` and `npm start`

The result was annoying

```
> myapp@0.18.1 start /home/code/serverSync/myapp/ui
> react-scripts start

sh: 1: react-scripts: not found

npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-23-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! myapp@0.18.1 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@0.18.1 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myapp package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs myapp
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls myapp
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/code/serverSync/myapp/ui/npm-debug.log
```

how can i revert back to master branch ?

Comment: You probably need to npm install again, it looks like the eject uninstalled some of the dependencies.

Comment: This should help https://todayilearned.cambraca.com/2018/02/undo-eject-operation-create-react-app-app

Comment: i followed that link also but no luck(rm -r scripts/ , $ rm -r config/ was already empty as i ran a git checkout)

Comment: followed @jonrsharpe suggestion `npm install` and  it was resolved (`react-scripts@1.1.0` was resinstalled). thank you.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can undo the "eject" operation of a Create React App app by adding the **react-scripts** package back. Command yarn or npm based on Your favorite **Package manager**

What you did:

```
$ yarn run eject/ npm run eject 
? Are you sure you want to eject? This action is permanent. (Yes/No)Yes
```

Now Solution for it is to:-

```
$ rm -r scripts/  //Remove Your scripts folder 
$ rm -r config/   //Remove Your config folder
$ rm -r node_modules//  //Remove Your node_modules folder
```

And Add **react-scripts** package back using

```
$ yarn add react-scripts / npm install react-scripts
```

And inside the *package.json* file you'll need to change the **"scripts"** to their former state:

```
"scripts": {
+    "start": "react-scripts start",                 
+    "build": "react-scripts build",                 
+    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",       
+    "eject": "react-scripts eject"                  
-    "start": "node scripts/start.js",               
-    "build": "node scripts/build.js",                
-    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"      
  }
```

Now install all dependency using:-

```
  $ yarn install / npm install
```

And You are good to go

```
$ yarn start / npm start
```

You made it.....

Answer (score 8):

If you're in now `master` branch (Which configuration is same as before `npm run eject`), then try following.

- Delete `node_module`
- `npm install`
- `npm start`

Answer (score 2):

Deletion and then `npm install` method mentioned is correct. However, if you are using git (or just any version control), just do:

```
git checkout -- .
```

or:

```
git stash
```

Answer (score -1):

DevTools can't closed completely. But you can make it inaccessible. Launching DevTools in the following ways

```js
// Disbale Right click
document.oncontextmenu = function (e) {
  if (e.button == 2) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
  }
}; 
  //disable f12 key
  document.onkeydown = function (event) {  
  event = (event || window.event);  
  if (event.keyCode == 123) {  
  return false;  
  }  
  }  
//disable ctrl key
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
      event.preventDefault();
  }   
});
```