# Invalid host error issue in webpack config file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am getting `Invalid Host header` after installing the node_modules in my project. Then I googled it and found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619644/i-am-getting-an-invalid-host-header-message-when-running-my-react-app-in-a-we). But don't where I need to add this line in `webpack.config.js`.

```
devServer: {
  compress: true,
  public: 'store-client-nestroia1.c9users.io' // That solved it
}
```

Can some one please help me to do the same.

**Edit** **1**: I have added it in `webpack.config.dev.js` but still no luck

Thank you!!!

Comment: You need to add devServer property like you write modules or entry in webpackConfig

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Please help me with some code. I never went through webpack configuration before. And please see the **Edit** part.

Comment: Re your ping to me on this: I'm afraid Webpack config isn't something I've gotten into. But it will help people who have help you if you post your `webpack.config.dev.js` (and confirm that Webpack is set to use that rather than `webpack.config.js`? I just note the difference in names...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Invalid Host header** come becuse of a configuration error in webpack configuration.

So just use **react-scripts** to run project and undo your webpack configuration.

If you did your webpack configuration setup using

```
$ npm run eject / yarn run eject
```

just [undo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454729/undo-npm-run-eject-in-react/54248621#54248621) **'npm run eject / yarn run eject'** from react project.

It worked for Me. May be helpful for you.