# yarn build in ReactJS, Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

In local enviroments I have no problem, but running a production enviroment on jenkins with this script it does:

```
yarn install --production
yarn build
```

The build takes like 5 minutes, in the end, jenkins exit with this console output error:

```
+ yarn install --production
yarn install v1.9.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > bootstrap@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3".
warning " > bootstrap@4.3.1" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.14.7".
warning " > google-maps-react@1.1.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0".
warning " > google-maps-react@1.1.11" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@~0.14.8 || ^15.0.0".
warning " > react-addons-css-transition-group@15.6.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.4.2".
warning " > react-bootstrap-table-next@3.1.5" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0.0".
warning " > react-bootstrap-table2-paginator@2.0.7" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0.0".
warning " > react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit@1.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.0.0".
warning " > react-intl@2.9.0" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.5.4".
warning " > react-simple-collapse@0.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^0.14.3".
warning " > react-simple-collapse@0.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "react-dom@^0.14.3".
warning " > react-widgets-globalize@5.0.20" has incorrect peer dependency "react-widgets@^4.2.2".
warning " > react-widgets-moment@4.0.27" has incorrect peer dependency "react-widgets@^4.2.2".
warning " > eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.6.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0".
warning "react-styleguidist > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.2.7" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
warning "react-styleguidist > webpack-dev-server@2.11.5" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 28.04s.
+ yarn build
yarn run v1.9.4
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[31498:0x2ab86d0]   229792 ms: Mark-sweep 1277.3 (1459.7) -> 1277.2 (1461.7) MB, 1801.1 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space requested
[31498:0x2ab86d0]   231676 ms: Mark-sweep 1277.2 (1461.7) -> 1277.0 (1420.7) MB, 1884.4 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
[31498:0x2ab86d0]   233210 ms: Mark-sweep 1277.0 (1420.7) -> 1277.0 (1419.2) MB, 1533.2 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0xb1707c25879 <JSObject>
    0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=0xb1707c090a9 <Object map = 0x123a95202ba1>,0x11b5562822d1 <undefined>,0x11b5562822d1 <undefined>,0x26b024683529 <Object map = 0x2449e8a328d1>)

    1: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    2: toString [0x11b5562822d1 <undefined>:9522] [bytecode=0xf76e19f6a69 offset=28](this=0xb3c89b82b29 <Object map = 0x306621cb3d19>)
    7: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous ...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8c21ec [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 6: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
 7: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::String>) [node]
 8: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
 9: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
10: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Stringify(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [node]
11: v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x14795198697d
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The only change that started to generate this error was the adition of 2 node dependencies:

```
"react-accessible-accordion": "^3.0.0",
"react-simple-collapse": "^0.1.2",
```

The full package.json is this:

```
{
  "name": "front-master",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@blueprintjs/select": "^2.0.1",
    "@esri/arcgis-to-geojson-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "@kenshooui/react-multi-select": "^1.1.5",
    "antd": "^3.12.1",
    "async": "^2.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "esri-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "fetch-jsonp": "^1.1.3",
    "globalize": "^1.4.2",
    "google-maps-react": "^1.1.11",
    "highcharts": "^6.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^3.0.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.3",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^10.0.4",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.1.2",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.0.6",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit": "^1.4.2",
    "react-color": "^2.14.1",
    "react-csv": "^1.0.15-RC2",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-data-export": "^0.5.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-export-excel": "^0.5.3",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-lineto": "^3.1.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "react-simple-collapse": "^0.1.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.8.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0",
    "react-widgets": "^5.0.0-7",
    "react-widgets-globalize": "^5.0.20",
    "react-widgets-moment": "^4.0.27",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "terraformer-wkt-parser": "^1.2.0",
    "video-react": "^0.14.1",
    "x2js": "^3.2.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.3.0",
    "react-docgen": "^2.21.0",
    "react-styleguidist": "^7.1.0"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also, I got this warning from github when I pushed my branch

[image]

So I checked `yarn.lock` and I can see that the version there is:

```
mem@^1.1.0:
  version "1.1.0"
```

But how could I upgrade a dependency that is not defined on `package.json` ?

Comment: This comment for them who came here with CRA v5, Webpack 5 and CRA v5 don't add fallbacks for nodejs modules any more, see this link for fixes https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756

Answer (score 29):

Finally, I use this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55378108/3541320

In my `package.json` the script for build:

```
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build"
```

Comment: This is the solution

Comment: Getting `FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Answer (score 22):

If you use a server with less memory (512MB) you need set try two things:

1 - Set less memory on react-scripts

```
"build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=256 build"
```

2 - You can disable generation of source maps as described in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration put in .env file:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false
```

Comment: Disabling sourcemap generation in production and staging solved it for us! As a matter of fact it is a desirable outcome for those environments not to have sourcemaps! Since we do the build locally on the machine that serves the build, it is rare to dedicate more than 1 or 2 GB of RAM for small Node.js web apps with a React frontend.

Comment: the second step of updating env variable worked for me

Comment: for ubuntu 18.04 aws ec2 server, this is the only solution
for latest,
"build": "react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=256 build"

Comment: First variant (max_old_space_size=256) gives me `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: Second variant (sourcemap) gives me `FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Comment: If not solved your problem, try use less memory. Try  use `--max_old_space_size=128`

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes increasing the memory allocation for node.js is not the solution you need. The most common culprit for this is caused by recursion which can arise from cyclic dependencies.

[Madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) is a tool that can help you detect when you have a cyclic dependency in your Nodejs/React Application

Add to your script

```
npm i -g madge

"madge": "madge  --image ./madge-graph.svg --extensions js,jsx,ts,tsx --circular .",
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it for me.
Had lots of circular dependencies.

It still built on my machine, just not on the server - Seems more memory adds some tolerance.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I do this and it works
Linux/macOS

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
```

please refer this [**URL**](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360002046418-JavaScript-heap-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the 2 dependencies you added use lot of memory, it would explain the error you get from jenkins.
Did you try to increase the memory allocated to jenkins as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5936519/how-to-give-jenkins-more-heap-space-when-it%C2%B4s-started-as-a-service-under-windows)?

Hope it will help you!

Comment: I tried to increase the memory for node with something like: `node --max-old-space-size=8192` but there I need the name of the file that I'm building. But I can't have the name before generating, it's something like `build.asdasdaq3d23nk2.js`

Comment: yeah in my case the aws npm packages were the culprit

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my case is ridiculous but I had to replace the 32-bit node with a 64-bit node.

Answer (score 0):

Doing npm cache clean --force resolve the problem for me

Comment: If you're not posting a fully explanatory answer, please post suggestions such as this as comments

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue change your heap & build memory through package.json file simple change script lines to this:

```
   "start": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 start",
   "build": "react-scripts --max_old_space_size=4096 build",
```

I got this solution from [boldreports](https://help.boldreports.com/embedded-reporting/react-reporting/how-to/how-to-resolve-the-javascript-memory-heap-out-issue/#:%7E:text=The%20memory%20heap%20out%20issue%20occurs%20when%20the%20heap%20size,in%20the%20below%20code%20snippet..)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this error, while using `react-i18next` with TypeScript types:

Having a translation file with just an empty object led to the "heap out of memory" error.

Breaks:

```js
export const EN_GB = {}
```

Works:

```js
export const EN_GB = {
  dummy: 'dummy'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue today. My code works fine when i run in local machine. But when i deploy it to netlify it shows the error you have mentioned above.

I have tried setting "max_old_space_size" variable and some other answers on other posts.
But none of them worked for me.

In my case, my node version in local machine differs from netlify site version.

So I edited environment variable with my local machine node version and the build is succesfully completed.

Answer (score -1):

I could fix it for one of my project like this :

On a newly created git branch run :

`npm run eject`

This will create many files and update your package json (the start/test/build commands if you haven't changed them).

Go to `config/webpack.config.js` and update the TerserPlugin options properties "compress" and "mangle" :

```
new TerserPlugin({
   terserOptions: {
      ...
      compress: false,
      mangle: true,
      ...
```

This has decreased drastically build time and memory usage...
The tradeoff is a slightly bigger build file (went from 2.3Mo to 2.6Mo for my project). So you should consider if it fits for your project in case of performance constraints.

Why this change ? I tried this because of the following info in the [Terser documentation](https://github.com/terser/terser#terser-fast-minify-mode) :

> It's not well known, but whitespace removal and symbol mangling accounts for 95% of the size reduction in minified code for most JavaScript - not elaborate code transforms.

If you want to "revert" the eject command : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54248621/4739462